# Error at declaring a private variable with file_get_contents

Tags: php, file, class

My HTML-soure after loading the php file is empty.

Can someone please tell me why i get this Error at declaring a private variable with file_get_contents?

```
class Main {
    private $order = file_get_contents("file.ini");
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I'm using PHP 5.3.28, and yes allow_url_fopen = On

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is not possible. declare it in the construct method.

```
class Main {
  private $order;
  public function __construct(){
    $this->order = file_get_contents("file.ini");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please! I never used the constructor.

Comment: @MartinDittrich just did

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will help you:

```
class Main {

    private $order;

    public function __construct($path) {
        $this->order = file_get_contents($path);
    }

    public function getOrder() {
        return $this->order;
    }

    public function setOrder($path) {
        $this->order = file_get_contents($path);
    }

}
```

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks, i had read some about the constructor but now i understand it :)

Comment: I will delete this comment later, can't post images yet... damn